# What are the changes we should make to our iOS 7 apps to support the 64-bit transition?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, 64-bit

I did find the [64 Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa Touch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Major64-BitChanges/Major64-BitChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH2-SW1) but to be honest, I find it to be very confusing. I use primarily CGFloat and int in my code, and in Core Data my integers are 64-bit. My app compiles and runs fine in the simulator for 64 bit, and on my iPhone 5, but I do not have a 5s to test with, so I cannot be sure. For example, what does it mean to "Fix alignment issues caused by changes in data type sizes." Is there something different that we need to do with pointers, which seem to have different sizes in 32 bit and 64 bit apps?

EDIT: I just changed my architectures to include 64-bit and it gave me a whole slew of errors, so that is a very helpful place to start.

EDIT2:[This Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH3-SW1) was actually a little more helpful than the one I had originally found.

Comment: Perhaps you can show the errors that you have problems with, to make this a more concrete question.

Comment: The errors are actually the answer to my question; my main error is "Implicit conversion loses integer precision." It is a lot easier to make the change to 64-bit when xCode shows you where the errors are; I was trying to guess where they would be, but changing the architecture to include 64-bit (a huge oversight on my part) actually solved the issue of the unclear transition guide for me

Comment: So far, in my particular code, I have changed a lot of ints to NSIntegers and [NSNumber numberWithInt:] to [NSNumber numberWithInteger:]

Comment: This page contains helpful information and tool for the 64-bit conversion https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/ConvertingExistingApp/ConvertingExistingApp.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to run the App on a Simulator that includes 64bit. Use iPad Air or iPhone6, or "Archive" the App. This will automatically show the warnings. The Simulators (iPad Air or iPhone6) will reliably reproduce 64bit problems.

However, I had about 100 warnings and one real problem. Casting a int to BOOL works differently in 64 bit. BOOL b=(BOOL)3; b==YES is FALSE in 32bit but TRUE in 64bit.

Another special case is NSNotFound, a value different on 32bit and 64bit! Look for Comparison of constant 'NSNotFound' (9223372036854775807) with expression of type 'int' is always false among the warnings.

In the end its about changing or casting tons of list counts (that never could hold long valued amount of objects anyway) in for loops. Useless work, IMO. Apple seems to want to save space on the devices by not including 32bit libs on 64bit platforms, or stripping apps?